# using Windows integrated authentication with SqlRoleProvider in silverlight application

Tags: windows, silverlight, iis-7, wcf-ria-services

I am working on web application that requires that users are put into roles and are given different permissions based on their roles. This can be easily done by using Forms Authentication and SqlRoleProvider. But, application will be used internally within corporate intranet, and forms authentication forces users to manually login every time they want to use application, Using Windows integrated autenthification looks much more elegant, since users are already logged on corporate domain. But there is a problem with roles here, integrated authentication by default uses roles that are built in users windows accounts (group membership and so on..). My application requires that i put users into custom made roles. So as far as roles are concerned having database i control is much more favorable solution. 
Is there a way to use Windows integrated authentification (for authentification) together with SqlRoleProvider (for roles and user management)?

Comment: IMHO this belongs to StackOverflow rather than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BenCr is right. But I wanted to avoid creating my own role provider and wanted to be able to add users with ease (through the Visual Studio built-in ASP.NET configuration tool)

So I found this on the net and it works. It ended up to being much simpler than I thought.
You just enable roles in web config file, Together with Windows Integrated Authentication. Copy your local mdf file (and attach it to sql server) and it works.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: You're right, it wasn't necessary to create own Provider, because he would be doing pretty much what the thefault SqlRolesProvider Does. Thanks to chare te link great Article!

Answer (score 4):

We've done exactly this in our application, you have to create your own RoleProvider and then specify that in your web.config. Then you can load your roles from whatever source you like.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyCompany.MyRoleProvider, MyAssembly" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

RoleProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

Comment: YOu're right, but as grabah pointed out, if you want to store the role infos in SQL Server, you could just use the default SqlRolesProvider ;)